# Java create multiple animated objects with independent behaviour patterns

Tags: java

I was attempting to create multiple animated bunnies from the same class but I seem not to be able to wrap my head around it, maybe someone can help. At the moment I have only one bunny in my scene (it hops to the right)

using this code here:

```
private void constructRootBunny(boolean preview)
{       
    GameObject bunnyRoot = new GameObject();

        game.RemoveBunnyObject(bunnyRoot);

    bunnyRoot.GetTransform().GetPos().Set(new Vector3f(506+bunny_X,500,506.5+bunny_Z)); 
    bunnyRoot.GetTransform().SetScale(new Vector3f(0.1,0.1,0.1));

    bunny_X += 0.005; // bunny 'hops' to the right

    if(preview == true) {   
            String bunnyFrame = bunny_WalkCycle.get(currentFrame); //obj files

            Mesh mesh = new Mesh(bunnyFrame );
            Material material = new Material (new Texture("bunny_Furr1.png"),
                            new Texture("diffuse_NRM.jpg"),
                            new Texture("diffuse_DISP.jpg"));
            bunnyRoot.AddComponent(new MeshRenderer(mesh, material));
        }

        game.AddBunnyObject(bunnyRoot);

    currentFrame++;

    if(currentFrame== 30) {
        currentFrame= 0; //resets animation
    }
}
```

see video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHvCHJp85Tc

I'm able to have multiple bunnies easily but they are static and I can't make them animated (not even simultaneously).. I don't know how to apply different behaviour patterns to the respective bunnies so that they would eventually act independently (have different animations, walk to different places and so on)..

Any ideas or suggestions what I could try out?

Comment: consider looking at the strategy pattern if you want different controlled behaviours (differently hopping bunnies so to speak) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: sounds interesting thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hard-coded your animation into your code.  You need to dynamically allocate the animation behavior.

You can do this using a set of predefined behaviors and using a [Random Number Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) to assign a behavior to a bunny.

As an idea, considering creating a `Behavior` class which provides abstract methods.  Then maybe consider making a `JumpBehavior` class that extends `Behavior` and which requires you to specify `hopFrequency`, `maximumHeight`, and `movementDirection`.   Then you can instantiate a couple of these `JumpBehaviors` using different arguments to create an array of unique behaviors.

Once you have assigned these behaviors to the bunnies, you can then update the bunnies on a per-frame basis.

```
public abstract class Behavior
{
    public abstract void initBehavior();
    public abstract void updateBunny(GameObject bunny);
}

public class JumpBehavior extends Behavior
{
    private long hopFrequency = 1000; //1 hop / 1000 milliseconds.
    private double maximumHeight = 20, movementVelocity = 0;

    public JumpBehavior(long hopFrequency, double maximumHeight, double movementVelocity)
    {
        this.hopFrequency = hopFrequency;
        this.maximumHeight = maximumHeight;
        this.movementVelocity = movementVelocity;
    }

    private long previousTimeMillis = 0;
    private long elapsedTimeMillis = 0;
    private long timeSinceHop = 0;

    public void initBehavior()
    {
        //Start the clock.
        previousTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        elapsedTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public void updateBunny(GameObject bunny)
    {
        //Implement logic to control bunny here.
        //Consider some randomization using a Random Number Generator.

        //Keep track of time.
        elapsedTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - previousTimeMills;

        //If velocity is negative, then we move left.
        bunny.X += movementVelocity * elapsedTimeMillis;

        timeSinceHop += elapsedTimeMillis;
        if (timeSinceHop >= hopFrequency)
        {
            //Reset counter, but keep the extra milliseconds passed.
            timeSinceHop -= hopFrequency;

            //Apply an acceleration to the bunny to start the hop.
            //Maybe add logic to make sure it doesn't hop while in the air.
            bunny.Velocity.Y += maximumHeight;
        }

        previousTimeMillis = elapsedTimeMillis;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, well hoping is not so flexible as you may think.. it's actually just an 30-frame animation exported from blender. After each frame I replace the existing bunny object (mesh.obj) with the obj file that has the next frame of this animation - my problem is rather that I want to have multiple bunnies, that all have this hoping animation but with different movement patterns so to say.. I will update my answer as soon as I made some progress, maybe at some point your suggestion can be implemented too, so thanks anyway!

Comment: thanks I could manage to make multiple bunnies now.. alas the animation doesn't work now because I have no way of tracking the loction, size and rotation of any bunny at a time.. I guess that's a different problem though..

Comment: Glad to know you solved your first problem.  As always, feel free to post another question if needed!